# Differential equation/Uniqueness of Solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

consider the following differential equation:
$$ y'(t)= \frac{cosy}{y^k} , y(0)=y_0, k\in \mathbb{Z}$$
Obviously $y(t)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ is a solution for $y(0)=\frac{\pi}{2}$
Beacause $\frac{cosy}{y^k}\in C^1(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\})$ f is lipschitz. Thus $y(t)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ is the only solution.
Is this right?

Comment: not right. any $y = (2n-1) \pi / 2$ is a Constant solution. Between, say $\pi/2$ and $3\pi/2,$ there are solutions with any $y(0)$ in between, asymptotic to both horizontal lines. For a simplified example, solve when $k = 0,$ that is $y' = \cos y$

Comment: The tasks says, that I have to show with Picard-Lindelöf, that  $y(t)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ is unique  for $y(0)=\frac{\pi}{2}$. How can I do that?

Comment: Because $\frac{cosy}{y^k}\in C^1(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\})$ f is lipschitz. , then this also holds for $y=\frac{\pi}{2}$Thus this solution is unique locally.

Comment: That seems right, more or less. I think this is a minor problem of English grammar. It was not clear to me that you meant to consider only the initial value problem with $y(0) = \pi/2$

Comment: Yes, sorry for that.Can I say something about global existence depending on k?

Comment: Separation of variables implies the existence and uniquenss of a solution for every $y_0 $, for which $\frac{cos y_0}{y_0^k} \ne 0$

Comment: How can I go on?